# Is it possible to optimize sql queries under these conditions

Tags: sql, database, optimization, query-optimization, sybase

Is is possible to somehow optimize the performance of the queries (apart from playing with hardware and OS settings) under these conditions

1) You can't add indexes.
2) You can't alter the queries themselves.

This is the common constraint while bench-marking the performance of a database.

I understand that the dbms has a query optimizer that plays a number game with all the statistics pertaining to accessing the tables touched by the query. Are there cases when the query optimizer comes up with sub optimal solutions. I know that you can force the optimizer to use a particular query plan. Not sure how to cache it though without altering the query plan. DB in question is Sybase

Comment: You can use query hints that force the compiler down a specific route, but I highly doubt you'll be able to come up with a better on than the system decides

Comment: Use table partitioning

Comment: Named caches would be another dba centric solution.  As Henrik mentioned below in point #4, inside the database server, you can set memory aside for use with particular tables/indexes/objects/etc.

Answer (score 2):

Independent of the specific case here (Sybase), there are multiple ways to optimize a query under the given conditions. Syntax is system-specific.

1. Most systems rely on statistics for finding the best query plan. So updating the statistics could help improve performance.
2. Many systems allow to set an optimization level independent of the application. This can have positive impact on the performance.
3. Many systems allow to re-use query plans for similar ad-hoc queries (dynamic SQL). Usually this has positive impact.
4. Allowing the database system (independent to the OS) to assign more memory to bottlenecks can also help.

What privileges do you have, what are the benchmark rules?

Comment: I have all the administrative privileges . Benchmark come with a set of queries on a particular dataset . You can't alter the queries or the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Data Henrik mentions optimisation level - you can set this system-wide for Sybase, or per session.

You can even have a flexible method that sets the level according to application name or login Id (see Rob Verschoor's Sybase site - login triggers.) I'd guess if you're not allowed to change queries or indexes you'd not likely be allowed to do this.

As far as I can tell you don't have a specific problem - you just mention benchmarking.

You should be sure all tables have UPDATE INDEX STATISTICS run on them, and you could then do your benchmarks with the 3 Sybase optimisation levels - OLTP, MIX, DSS.

If you have specific problems, that's another subject.

Comment: No, its a general problem of improving system wide performance. Queries used by the benchmark or indexes created by the benchmark scripts can be changed are the only constraints as far as I know.